# How to find the contract wallet JSON and ABI

Tags: wallets, json-rpc, abi, myetherwallet, multisignature

I'm trying to find the JSON and ABI for one of my contract wallets here:

> 0x1Fa0926C69eEe89d212F0848803e4Ee2E548fE4D

The reason is that there is some ETC locked up in it that I'm trying to dump, via myetherwallet now that they have the functionality to interact with contracts on the ETC chain...but in order to do that I need the ABI/JSON. Where do I find that? The wallet contract is a multi-sig contract with 2 owners.

Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6827/wheres-the-solidity-code-for-mists-default-multi-sig-contract-wallet

Answer (score 7):

Just got in touch with avsa who was kind enough to point me in the correct direction:

```
[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"removeOwner","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_addr","type":"address"}],"name":"isOwner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"m_numOwners","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"m_lastDay","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"version","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"resetSpentToday","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"m_spentToday","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"addOwner","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"m_required","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_h","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"confirm","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_newLimit","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setDailyLimit","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"execute","outputs":[{"name":"_r","type":"bytes32"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_operation","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"revoke","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_newRequired","type":"uint256"}],"name":"changeRequirement","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_operation","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"hasConfirmed","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"}],"name":"kill","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"}],"name":"changeOwner","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"m_dailyLimit","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_owners","type":"address[]"},{"name":"_required","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_daylimit","type":"uint256"}],"type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"operation","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"Confirmation","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"operation","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"Revoke","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"oldOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnerChanged","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnerAdded","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"oldOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnerRemoved","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"newRequirement","type":"uint256"}],"name":"RequirementChanged","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Deposit","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"SingleTransact","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"operation","type":"bytes32"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"MultiTransact","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"operation","type":"bytes32"},{"indexed":false,"name":"initiator","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"ConfirmationNeeded","type":"event"}]
```

From: https://github.com/ethereum/meteor-dapp-wallet/blob/develop/app/client/lib/ethereum/walletInterface.js#L7

What you do from here is beyond me. But please keep us updated on your progress as I would LOVE to make a tutorial covering this information.

In version 3.4.5 I will add a button to autofill in this ABI.

Comment: OK so the JSON that you provided is correct, I now have access to the contract, however, what to do now? There is a drop down list of READ/WRITE to contract, but no "SEND" option. Here is the list:

removeOwner isOwner m_numOwners m_lastday version resetSpendToday M_spentToday addOwner m_required confirm SetDailyLimit execute revoke changeRequirement hasConfirmed kill changeOwner m_daily limit

My question is which one do I use to send the ETC out of there? I am leaning towards EXECUTE and KILL.

Comment: Under EXECUTE I get the options:

_to address: (need a ETC address here) _value uint256: Is this the amount of ETC I want to send? _data bytes: have no idea what this is...leave it blank?

Under KILL I get:

_to address: insert ETC address here.

My question is, which one do I use to send the ETC to a address of my choice? If I use KILL then doesn't that kill the contract and send the funds to the original contract creators? Or do I use EXECUTE?

Thanks

Comment: I have exactly the same questions - how in heck do I interact with a wallet contract that I have created in the original ethereum wallet software (the precursor of mist).

How do one do simple things like view balances, and transfer eth, or other tokens such as DAO tokens from it.

These very basic answers are nearly impossible to get to.