# How to find the contract wallet JSON and ABI thanks

Tags: contract-debugging, ethereum-classic

I'm trying to find the JSON and ABI for one of my contract wallets with multi key here:

`73fd0499558056bede6b5f7b31ca59936deda1d4` -

`d38b4e14167a75adb77d19acd5ebdf59473ffb4c` -

`3da3e8c60a70aa94ce9b50f4288f05e078948ea7`

and or 
`a80c0ec73d34421c4b901f496a81c651c29c3050`

The reason is that there is some ETC locked up in it that I'm trying to dump, via myetherwallet now that they have the functionality to interact with contracts on the ETC chain...but in order to do that I need the ABI/JSON. Where do I find that? The wallet contract is a multi-sig contract with 2 owners.

Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6827/wheres-the-solidity-code-for-mists-default-multi-sig-contract-wallet

Comment: What software did you use to create the wallets?

Comment: I use mist wallet.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to track this down with [http://etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/). You can query for an address and track down the contract and contract source associated with it. For example, for the first address, I think https://etherscan.io/address/0x3b3b1c9f68ce3266ff3cf2ce63e638611f393209#code is what you are looking for.

Comment: If you know of another site or I could access my contract cella will help me enormously.

Answer (score 0):

Yes thanks! that's what I was looking for I noted the address on Mist and I have my 3 keys but balance is 0 ether on mist how to update mist? The balance of my other accounts also are a 0 on Mist that is why I used myetherwallet but on the site the address of the contract is valid but I can use the feature options.

I am sorry for my English I am French.