# "Standard" Mist/Ethereum Multisig Wallet Safe?

Tags: mist, wallets, multisignature, parity-wallet

I made a multisig wallet using Mist or EthereumWallet (don't remember exactly) in July 2016 and put some ETH inside. Now, given the Parity hack a few days ago, I am wondering if my multisig wallet is still safe. I am not a programmer so I couldn't "audit" the code.

I hope there was no bug at the time?!

I think the code used for my multisig wallet is discussed here, but I am not sure: 
[Where's the Solidity code for Mist's default multi-sig contract wallet?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6827/wheres-the-solidity-code-for-mists-default-multi-sig-contract-wallet)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Your multisig wallet is **not** vulnerable to the Parity multisig hack recently. There is no known vulnerability in the standard Mist multisig wallet.

That said, if your wallet was created prior to June 2016, it may have a different vulnerability discussed here: https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/06/24/security-alert-smart-contract-wallets-created-in-frontier-are-vulnerable-to-phishing-attacks/

It sounds like yours is later than this, and this attack can only affect you if you are actively using the account associated with the owner of the wallet to call functions in untrusted contracts. New versions of Mist will warn you if you have this vulnerability, so if you do not see a warning, then there is no problem.