# Multi-Sig Contracts Comparison

Tags: multisignature

I'd like to see a comparison of features (audited, how active it is, last modification, usage in real world, ..) among the known multisig wallets: this for creating a reference comparison for choosing the best-fitting for a given use-case.

I've searched around but people seem to be suggesting different things. For example, this thread [Where's the Solidity code for Mist's default multi-sig contract wallet?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6827/wheres-the-solidity-code-for-mists-default-multi-sig-contract-wallet) says dapp-bin is outdated and to use this [meteor-dapp-wallet contract](https://github.com/ethereum/meteor-dapp-wallet/blob/master/Wallet.sol). But I see the last modification on Git for dapp-bin is much newer.
https://github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/blob/master/wallet/wallet.sol

This is another option: https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet/blob/master/contracts/MultiSigWallet.sol

Comment: Maybe by requesting a comparison table instead of which one is the best the question would come off hold.

Comment: Stackexchanges are question and answer sites. Having a comparison of features is not the purpose of the site. It will get out of date very quickly, and it is hard to mantain properly. A wiki or something similar seems more appropiate for such thing.

Comment: @ismael are you saying that all comparisons are vulnerable to change or that you should never provide an answer that could become false in the future?  

To me, a comparison table seems a legitimate way to answer a question.  Asking for one should be permitted

Comment: @user1938620 No. I'm saying that stackexchange's sites are about questions and answers, where old question are not updated frequently. IMHO there are better places to have a comparision where they can be mantained properly, like a wiki for example. But I don't decide anything here if you ask for a comparison get replies and the people see value there and keep it, then there's no problem. In case of doubts you can ask in ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com for clarification.

Comment: Gnosis (the last option on your question) works pretty well for me. AFAIK, it is currently also the one which is the most thoroughly-audited.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the EIP aiming to standardise: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/763

> Currently, there is no common API nor implementation for multisig wallets. Being an owner of multiple multisig wallets with different APIs is a hard job, because one needs to use different tools/calls for the same operations on different wallet. This is inconvenient and error-prone. Standard API will make it possible to create convenient and secure tools one could make to deal with all his multisig wallets in the same way.

Here is my write-up - https://steemit.com/ethereum/@genesisre/ethereum-multisig-wallet-interacting-with-contracts-on-behalf-of-multisig - as I was doing research I've encountered your post.

We are still in early days, no standards, ecosystem is moving fast.